# Transfer ovpn file from CentOs 7 to iOS without iTunes

Tags: openvpn, ios, itunes

My openvpn server running on CentOS 7, I've got 20 or so users with modern IOS devices half with iOS 11. We generate .ovpn scripts with python, and used iTunes to configure the IOS OpenVPN client, until Apple broke it.

As of iTunes 12.7, all features for managing apps have been removed. In particular, users cannot use iTunes to load files into particular apps. These was the recommended way to install ovpn files into OpenVPN for iOS. Older versions of iTunes retain this functionality, but it is not compatible with devices newer than iPhone 5, iPad Air.
So now what do I do? I'm going try to serve via apache http, because I saw a post that hinted that you can configure MIME metadata to get iOS safari to open a file in OpenVPN. I've never seen that work, so I'm skeptical.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via Dropbox. On the iOS device open the Dropbox app, select the file and then export. choose the option `Open In` and then `Copy to OpenVPN`.

Comment: Looks like this will work! I downloaded "Linux Dropbox Uploader" from github, jumped through a few easy hoops, and used the bash script to upload a test file through Dropbox into OpenVPN. It's not ideal for managing lots of users, but it's workable. Thanks!

Comment: Dropbox uploaded is at https://www.andreafabrizi.it/2016/01/01/Dropbox-Uploader/